# Xcode crashing when displaying array in table

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am Getting

> fatal error: Index out of range" and "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" at line "cell.textLabel?.text =
>   String(arrayTable[indexPath.row])

When I test my function in playground it works as expected. My array get populated. So, I don't understand why Xcode won't find any value in my array.

any idea?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

@IBAction func sliderSelector(_ sender: Any) {
   arrayTable = [Int]()
    tableGenerate()
}

var arrayTable = [Int]()


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 50
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(arrayTable[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func tableGenerate () {
    var tableMultiplier = 1
    while tableMultiplier <= 50 {
        arrayTable.append(tableMultiplier * Int(slider.value))
        tableMultiplier += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: `fatal error: Index out of range` Means `numberOfRowsInSection` not sync with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with your array count.

Comment: as suggested below, changing return 50 to return arrayTable.count fixed the crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty common mistake for newbies is to return from `numberOfRowsInSection` any magic number. Instead of that you should return your real items count: `return arrayTable.count` and i believe all should work fine.

Comment: but the after initialize array the tablview not update so u should to reload its data

Comment: it fixed the crash but the table does not display the array, looking for that now, @DivyeshGondaliya do you know how to reload ?

Comment: check my answer @Dev0urCode

Comment: I did but I'm sorry I do not understand where you mean to reload ?

Comment: @Dev0urCode just call `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: so sorry Im a complete noob at this but where would you put it ? since it is related to the tableView I would put it in the tableView function but I get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff52a4dff8)
I tried everywhere else without success either

Comment: tried in both numberOfRowsInSection and CellForRowAt
first one gives the error above
second one doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: I also tried to put self.tableView.reloadData () but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try to make changes like this

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayTable.count
    }

    func tableGenerate () {
        var tableMultiplier = 1
        while tableMultiplier <= 50 {
            arrayTable.append(tableMultiplier * Int(slider.value))
            tableMultiplier += 1
        }
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         print(arrayTable)
         tblview.reloadData()
      }
    }
```

Comment: create your tableview object first and then reload it here its working and also check that your tableview datasource or delegate given or not @Dev0urCode

Comment: I write what you suggested but I get "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'"
I also did put the tableGenerate function after the tableView functions

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4jSwWmqfOA watch this and get note where you not doing well @Dev0urCode

Comment: I can't see any tableView.reloadData () anywhere in the video :(

Comment: just watch you give delegate datasource method to your viewcontroller or not or how to create object of tableview @Dev0urCode

Comment: also check before tableviewreloaddata your array will de initialize or not  in your case print(arrayTable) @Dev0urCode

Comment: Thanks for our help but I can't work it out. I have given the permissions as the video shows and I have created the object, everything that the video shows I have done. everything works if I create a static array. I don't understand why the array would "deinitialise" also this thread began with another issue so I think I'll create a new thread.

Comment: if u in trubble give me a your project i help u if u comfortable with that @Dev0urCode

Comment: Thanks that's really nice of you, I don't mind sending you my project but I can't initialise chat cause I don't have enough rep lol really trying to understand this reloadData thing

Comment: what u get in slider.value ?

Comment: the print(arrayTable) inside tableGenerate shows in the console that my table gets updated correctly
If I check the slider value it gets Double values from 1 to 20 (set by myself)

Comment: ok then first time when you run whats you get in your array print it and check array is initialize or not @Dev0urCode

Comment: if I put print(arrayTable) in viewDidLoad I get an empty array as expected. if I move my slider the console shows the array gets updated but the table does not display

Comment: see video at 1:40 you get that u set this type of delegate and datasource or not ? @Dev0urCode

Comment: yes all done. I created a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736553/tableview-reloaddata-table-not-updating

Comment: ok if this answer is valuable for u then accept this answer and give upvote @Dev0urCode

Answer (score 0):

When the view loads, your tableView will attempt to return 50 cells. For each cell you're trying to assign the textlabel text to:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = String(arrayTable[indexPath.row])
```

But because the arrayTable is empty when the view loads, the application crashes when it's trying to access an index by indexPath.row.

Answer (score 0):

problem in this method

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return yourArray.count
}
```