# tableView.reloadData() Table not updating

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

The table does not display the updated array to return to the cell. When I launch the app I get blank cells. All permissions have been given in the storyboard. I tried the `tableView.reloadData()` everywhere but can't seem to make it work either. If anyone can explain where Im going wrong that would really help me get better.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

@IBAction func sliderSelector(_ sender: Any) {
    tableGenerate()
}

var arrayTable = [Int]()

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayTable.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(arrayTable[indexPath.row])
    tableView.reloadData()
    return cell
}

func tableGenerate () {
    var tableMultiplier = 1
    while tableMultiplier <= 50 {
        arrayTable.append(tableMultiplier * Int(slider.value))
        tableMultiplier += 1
        print(arrayTable)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you call `tableView.reloadData()` inside `cellForRowAt`? That puts you in in infinite loop, since it will again call `cellForRowAt`... You only need to call `tableView.reloadData()` if you change the data source after your table view was set up.

Comment: the data gets updated when the slider moves. wrong ?

Comment: Yes, so you should call `tableView.reloadData()` from inside `sliderSelector` or rather do it from inside `tableGenerate()`... @Dev0urCode check my answer.

Comment: You only have to populate `arrayTable` and call `tableView.reloadData()` **once**. That will get the number of rows from `numberOfRowsInSection` and will ask you for the initialized cell (in `cellForRowAt`). So `cellForRowAt` should return the `UITableViewCell` **only**, and do nothing more.

Comment: @DávidPásztor if I put tableview.reloaddata in the slider section I get Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

Comment: It seems like you did not create an IBOutlet for your tableView, you need to do that. Since you are not using a `UITableViewController`, you need to do this manually.

Comment: @DávidPásztor You are right; progress !! I forgot to create the outlet ! I also forgot to reset the array with the array slider with arrayTable = [] now it works fine. I don't have the tick to accept answer in response to the first post somehow. I'll create an answer. thanks a million !

Comment: @DávidPásztor if you create a reply I'll tick it

Comment: I already did, [this is it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736732/4667835)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `tableView.reloadData()` inside `cellForRowAt`, you create an infinite loop, since `reloadData()` automatically calls `cellForRowAt`. You need to move `reloadData()` inside `tableGenerate()`, since it should only be called when your data source is changed.

You also need to create an IBOutlet for your tableView in `Storyboard`. Since you are not using a `UITableViewController`, you need to do this manually.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

    @IBAction func sliderSelector(_ sender: Any) {
        tableGenerate()
    }

    var arrayTable = [Int]()

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayTable.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(arrayTable[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableGenerate () {
        var tableMultiplier = 1
        while tableMultiplier <= 50 {
            arrayTable.append(tableMultiplier * Int(slider.value))
            tableMultiplier += 1
            print(arrayTable)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add outlet of tableview like this and connect with table in storyboard-

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
```

Change code to this -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!

@IBAction func sliderSelector(_ sender: Any) {
    tableGenerate()
}

var arrayTable = [Int]()

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayTable.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(arrayTable[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func tableGenerate () {
    var tableMultiplier = 1
    while tableMultiplier <= 50 {
        arrayTable.append(tableMultiplier * Int(slider.value))
        tableMultiplier += 1
    }
        print(arrayTable)
    tableView1.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: if I do that i get Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' at tableView.reloadData line

Comment: than that gives me Use of unresolved identifier 'tableView1'

Comment: You are right; progress !! I forgot to create the outlet ! 
I created @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView! and it works by updating on the first move of the slider to the initial slider value but when I move the slider further it does not update anymore.

Comment: using table.reloadData()

Comment: I found the issue, forgot to add arrayTable = [] in my sliderslector so I thought the table was not updating when in fact it was just getting bigger. Thanks a million for your help !

Answer (score -1):

forgot to create the table outlet ! I also forgot to reset the array with the array slider with arrayTable = [] now it works fine